# App Uploader and iTunesArtwork extension error

Tags: iphone, distribution, app-store-connect

I'm getting an an error when trying to upload a new version of my app to the store using the Application Uploader. It says:

"Icon specified in the Info.plist CFBundleIconFile does not have an extension:iTunesArtwork"

From what I can tell, the iTunesArtwork is not supposed to have an extension. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunesArtwork is 512x512 image that you include for iTunes' benefit. You can either stick it in the .ipa (beside Payload/) or in the .app itself; sticking it into the .app might have benefits (it's copied to the device, so iTunes can copy it back off later. But I'm not sure abut this.)

CFBundleIconFile should point to a 59x59 PNG image. The default name is Icon.png. On iOS 4 and above, you should additionally be using CFBundleIconFiles to get high-res images.

I just name my images Icon.png, Icon-72.png, Icon@2x.png, and don't bother including the keys in Info.plist (I originally did this because iTunes Connect rejected CFBundleIconFiles for apps compiled against 3.1.3, and we didn't have time to implement all the OS 4 fixes before release).

Comment: Thanks. I deleted iTunesArtwork from the pList (not from the app), submitted it, and everything seems ok.